# Convert Objective-C (#define) macro to Swift

Tags: swift, generics, struct, enums, swift2

Put simply I am trying to convert a `#define` macro into a native Swift data structure of some sort. Just not sure how or what kind.

#### Details

I would like to try and replicate the following `#define` from Objective-C to Swift. [Source: JoeKun/FileMD5Hash](https://github.com/JoeKun/FileMD5Hash/blob/master/Library/FileHash.m#L48-54)

```
#define FileHashComputationContextInitialize(context, hashAlgorithmName)                    \
    CC_##hashAlgorithmName##_CTX hashObjectFor##hashAlgorithmName;                          \
    context.initFunction      = (FileHashInitFunction)&CC_##hashAlgorithmName##_Init;       \
    context.updateFunction    = (FileHashUpdateFunction)&CC_##hashAlgorithmName##_Update;   \
    context.finalFunction     = (FileHashFinalFunction)&CC_##hashAlgorithmName##_Final;     \
    context.digestLength      = CC_##hashAlgorithmName##_DIGEST_LENGTH;                     \
    context.hashObjectPointer = (uint8_t **)&hashObjectFor##hashAlgorithmName
```

Obviously `#define` does not exist in Swift; therefore I'm not looking for a 1:1 port. More generally just the spirit of it.

To start, I made an `enum` called `CryptoAlgorithm`. I only care to support two crypto algorithms for the sake of this question; but there should be nothing stopping me from extending it further.

```
enum CryptoAlgorithm {
  case MD5, SHA1
}
```

So far so good. Now to implement the `digestLength`.

```
enum CryptoAlgorithm {
  case MD5, SHA1

  var digestLength: Int {
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
      return Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    case .SHA1:
      return Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
  }
}
```

Again, so far so good. Now to implement the `initFunction`.

```
enum CryptoAlgorithm {
  case MD5, SHA1

  var digestLength: Int {
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
      return Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    case .SHA1:
      return Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
  }

  var initFunction: UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_MD5_CTX> -> Int32 {
    switch self {
    case .MD5:
      return CC_MD5_Init
    case .SHA1:
      return CC_SHA1_Init
    }
  }
}
```

Crash and burn. `'CC_MD5_CTX' is not identical to 'CC_SHA1_CTX'`. The problem is that `CC_SHA1_Init` is a `UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_SHA1_CTX> -> Int32`. Therefore, the two return types are not the same.

Is an `enum` the wrong approach? Should I be using generics? If so, how should the generic be made? Should I provide a protocol that both `CC_MD5_CTX` and `CC_SHA1_CTX` and then are extended by and return that?

All suggestions are welcome (except to use an Objc bridge).

Comment: How about `var initFunction: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> -> Int32 { ... }`?

Comment: Unfortunately `'Void' is not identical to 'CC_MD5_CTX'`. Also tried `Any` to no avail. `'Any' is not identical to 'CC_MD5_CTX'`.

Comment: Can you include the definition for `CC_MD5_Init` and `CC_SHA1_Init`?

Comment: Sure they are all from the CommonCrypto library. [Source: CommonDigest.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-7/CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if I love where this is going in the original ObjC code, because it's pretty type-unsafe. In Swift you just need to make all the type unsafety more explicit:

```
    var initFunction: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> -> Int32 {
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            return { CC_MD5_Init(UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_MD5_CTX>($0)) }
        case .SHA1:
            return { CC_SHA1_Init(UnsafeMutablePointer<CC_SHA1_CTX>($0)) }
        }
    }
```

The more "Swift" way of approaching this would be with protocols, such as:

```
protocol CryptoAlgorithm {
    typealias Context
    init(_ ctx: UnsafeMutablePointer<Context>)
    var digestLength: Int { get }
}
```

Then you'd have something like (untested):

```
struct SHA1: CryptoAlgorithm {
    typealias Context = CC_SHA1_CONTEXT
    private let context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Context>
    init(_ ctx: UnsafeMutablePointer<Context>) {
        CC_SHA1_Init(ctx) // This can't actually fail
        self.context = ctx // This is pretty dangerous.... but matches above. (See below)
    }
    let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
}
```

But I'd be strongly tempted to hide the context, and just make it:

```
protocol CryptoAlgorithm {
    init()
    var digestLength: Int { get }
}

struct SHA1: CryptoAlgorithm {
    private var context = CC_SHA1_CTX()
    init() {
        CC_SHA1_Init(&context) // This is very likely redundant.
    }
    let digestLength = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
}
```

Why do you need to expose the fact that it's CommonCrypto under the covers? And why would you want to rely on the caller to hold onto the context for you? If it goes out of scope, then later calls will crash. I'd hold onto the context inside.

---

Getting more closely to your original question, consider this (compiles, but not tested):

```
// Digests are reference types because they are stateful. Copying them may lead to confusing results.
protocol Digest: class {
    typealias Context
    var context: Context { get set }
    var length: Int { get }
    var digester: (UnsafePointer<Void>, CC_LONG, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8> { get }
    var updater: (UnsafeMutablePointer<Context>, UnsafePointer<Void>, CC_LONG) -> Int32 { get }
    var finalizer: (UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Context>) -> Int32 { get }
}

// Some helpers on all digests to make them act more Swiftly without having to deal with UnsafeMutablePointers.
extension Digest {
    func digest(data: [UInt8]) -> [UInt8] {
        return perform { digester(UnsafePointer<Void>(data), CC_LONG(data.count), $0) }
    }
    func update(data: [UInt8]) {
        updater(&context, UnsafePointer<Void>(data), CC_LONG(data.count))
    }
    func final() -> [UInt8] {
        return perform { finalizer($0, &context) }
    }
    // Helper that wraps up "create a buffer, update buffer, return buffer"
    private func perform(f: (UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> ()) -> [UInt8] {
        var hash = [UInt8](count: length, repeatedValue: 0)
        f(&hash)
        return hash
    }
}

// Example of creating a new digest
final class SHA1: Digest {
    var context = CC_SHA1_CTX()
    let length = Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let digester = CC_SHA1
    let updater = CC_SHA1_Update
    let finalizer = CC_SHA1_Final
}

// And here's what you change to make another one
final class SHA256: Digest {
    var context = CC_SHA256_CTX()
    let length = Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let digester = CC_SHA256
    let updater = CC_SHA256_Update
    let finalizer = CC_SHA256_Final
}

// Type-eraser, so we can talk about arbitrary digests without worrying about the underlying associated type.
// See http://robnapier.net/erasure
// So now we can say things like `let digests = [AnyDigest(SHA1()), AnyDigest(SHA256())]`
// If this were the normal use-case, you could rename "Digest" as "DigestAlgorithm" and rename "AnyDigest" as "Digest"
// for convenience
final class AnyDigest: Digest {
    var context: Void = ()
    let length: Int
    let digester: (UnsafePointer<Void>, CC_LONG, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>
    let updater: (UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UnsafePointer<Void>, CC_LONG) -> Int32
    let finalizer: (UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Int32

    init<D: Digest>(_ digest: D) {
        length = digest.length
        digester = digest.digester
        updater = { digest.updater(&digest.context, $1, $2) }
        finalizer = { (hash, _) in digest.finalizer(hash, &digest.context) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't really _want_ to expose the fact that it is CommonCrypto. If there is a better way of doing it I'm all ears. All I really would like to be able to do is define some function with a signature something like `func digest(also: CryptoAlgorithm)`. Within that function generalize based on all the supported digest algorithms. To your point it wouldn't matter, to me, if the conceptual `digest` function or the `enum` had the generalized `CC_INIT` reference. I was really just trying to find a way to define a variable that would always work.

Comment: Updated with an impl that I think is closer to your original goal by reducing some code duplication and making digest types purely configuration.