# How do I access a objective-c defined macro in swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a shared delegate defined by a macro in an Objective-C class. I would like to access this shared delegate from a Swift class. I have defined my shared instance as:

```
#define APP_DELEGATE((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

I have a property declared in my AppDelegate that I would like to access from my Swift class:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isReady;
```

How would I accomplish this in Swift? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Convert Objective-C (#define) macro to Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326057/convert-objective-c-define-macro-to-swift)

Comment: create a function of some sort for that, or a stored property or whatever, dont use the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really bad design choice but you just simply create a function

```
func appDelegate() -> AppDelegate {
  return UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something similar. I just added a class method within my App Delegate and returned a shared instance.